# Blank white screenshots while taking screenshots with selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2) I was able to take screenshots but they turned out to be just white. I tried couple of workarounds with no avail

1. Tried using one monitor instead of usual two
2. Used different image format
3. Included System.Drawing reference even though I didn't an compiler error.

Code

> Screenshot ss=((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
>   ss.SaveAsFile("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

What should be my next steps. I am using C# 4.0

Comment: What is the application you are taking a screenshot of? As Matt has said it can depend on what you are capturing. It could also be you are focusing on a different window when taking the screenshot?

Comment: I was hoping taking screenshot of the firefox window. If I see some output, instead of white screen then I would know that I am atleast in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I was not using the selenium API correctly. I doubt any one would again do the same mistake again but here is the fix. I did the first call

> Screenshot ss=((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

in a constructor and second savefile at the place I want to create the screenshot

> ss.SaveAsFile("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

They both should be combined at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are taking a screenshot of WebGL object?
Traditional screenshots may not work in this case.

Comment: Its firefox window that I am hoping to capture and it does not have any webgl objects