# How do I take a Selenium screenshot when an MSpec assertion fails?

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, mspec

I am using the MSpec test framework/runner and the Selenium Web Driver. I want to take a screenshot whenever a test fails and saves it so that I can see the error later. I am thinking there can be two possibilities:

- Does MSpec have an assertion-failed event? Something like the cleanup interfaces?
- Does Selenium have some kind of failure event that can automatically take the screenshot?

Can anyone please tell me if you have done something similar and how?

---

There is a similar question answered already here but my scenario is different. **I don't want to modify my tests** and put a try catch there in every test.

Answer (score 0):

Although Selenium happily supports taking screenshots (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2) on taking screenshots in C#), it will have no knowledge of the test runner you are using it within. In fact, as a multi-purpose browser driver, it may be used for a lot of other tasks in addition to testing.

You'll need to add some kind of hook to your MSpec runner on failure to trigger this code. I have done something similar which worked great with JUnit in Java (an @Rule for failures), I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with MSpec to suggest what to use here. I do suggest you have your screenshots published as a build test artifact for easy access in a CI environment.

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/agross/mspec-samples/tree/master/WebSpecs/LoginApp.Selenium.Specs

Comment: @AlexanderGroß, I don't see where you're taking the screenshot on failure.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean MSpec does that automatically because we have a ResultSupplementer in our specs assembly. https://github.com/agross/mspec-samples/blob/master/WebSpecs/LoginApp.Selenium.Specs/SeleniumSupport.cs