# Selenium Chrome screenshot generates randomly whitespace

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium (Chrome driver) to generate screenshots of a page. But sometimes the generated screenshot has whitespace in bottom of the screenshot. It happens randomly. It looks like the render just stops (see screenshot attached).

**I tried**

- Updated to the latest version of Chrome (60.0.3112.101)
- Updated to the latest version of Selenium.WebDriver (3.5.1)
- Disabled "no-sandbox" and "headless" argument

**Code**

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(Server.MapPath("bin"), chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));    
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someurl.com");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(220);
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(4000, 3000);

((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshote.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

driver.Close();
driver.Quit();
```

**Screenshot**

Here is a simple render of a bg image where the render failed.
[image]

**Update**

I cannot give a link to the url, but the same url never fails rendering if I use PhantomJS.

Comment: IMO, it din't fail. Can you get us the `url` and the expected screenshot?

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry I can't, because it's running in an internal system.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, I was getting the same problem when using external JAVA library for screenshots, but the problem was that I was taking full page screenshot so scrolling the page was a necessary thing and then screenshots were merged into one with whitespaces. Does not look the same with your case.

I see you're using `driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(4000, 3000);` 
Perhaps you may try to expand your window in full screen just to see the difference?

I tried to search for external screenshotting frameworks for C# but could not find anyhting :( 
There are some posts here (ex. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3346017/5971690) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16795458/5971690)) that you might want to check if they contain alternative screenshoting solutions if this bug is critical for your tests.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Mykola! I tried the Full Screen method instead of Size=4000,3000, but it did not work. It's also strange that this happens randomly.. It looks like we have to go back to PhantomJS.