# Capture a screenshot of Google Map Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot of a `Google Map` without using a static map in asp.net.

The features I need are not in the static map `API`, including rotation of the map, traffic, and so on.

I've used several libraries, including the [C# web browser](https://github.com/AlexSanseau/Web.Screenshot), [CEFSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/), but none of the ability to take screenshots from the Google map.

For example, my problem with the C# web browser is to load the Google map after the DocumentCompleted event.
The resulting image was displayed as [gray content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao6Yl.jpg).

How can I get a screenshot of Google Map Programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works very well for browser automation in C#.  Without knowing your use case not sure if launching a full chrome / Firefox instance will suffice however you can definitely use it launch the browser, navigate to the map, and screenshot.

How to screenshot in Selenium / C# has been nicely answered in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2) .

Comment: I want to take screenshot programmatically within web application and i don't want to open browser to take screenshot

Comment: You could try using a headless browser like https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash .  This is also provided as a service here: https://scrapinghub.com/splash .  I've used it in a number of projects and works very well

Comment: I need library written in C#, Can you give me a solution?