# Generate pdf that contains highcharts (without rendering an html page)

Tags: c#, service, highcharts, pdf-generation

My initial requirement is to create a pdf that contains highcharts and send it to users. As per my initial analysis it seems that in order to display highcharts it needs to be rendered in an html page by running on a browser and then converting it to pdf.

I am working on  windows service and I am using html agility pack to dynamically generate html pages. Is there anyway I can render this and convert this page to pdf?

(or)

can someone suggest any other way to dynamically generate highcharts without rendering and converting them to pdfs straight from the C# code.

**Edit:**
***The answer Sebastian suggested was greatly appreciated. Can somebody suggest any other alternatives or other solutions to resolve this scenario?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible solutions:

As per this Answer ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2)) 
you could use Selenium to create a screenshot of a html page and add that to your PDF file.

Another possible way is to use [wkhtmltopdf.org](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which offers a similar capability but through the commandline or a C-library (There are multiple C# wrapper but i've not tested any of them)

a third solution would be WPF which can save any displayable control to an image.