# Selenium ChromeDriver doesn't navigate URL after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, iis-8

I'm using selenium C# chrome driver to access some website and download data from it. This is a sample code of my application.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            AppSettingsReader configReader = new AppSettingsReader();
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath)) //here I used latest chrome driver(V 2.42.59)
            {
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                //driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

                driver.Url = "https://crims.crib.lk";
                var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("txtUserName");
                var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("txtPassword");
                driver.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogWriter(" WebApplication2.Controllers", ex, "HomeController", "Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

This code is working properly when I execute code through VS. After publishing the application through IIS server, Driver does not navigate to the URL. Following error showing in the log file.

```
Source :WebApplication2
Module:HomeController
Method:Index
Message :no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"id","selector":"txtUserName"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088
(7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT
6.2.9200 x86_64)
StackTrace :   at
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
errorResponse)
```

This same error occurred in VS when the browser does not navigate to URL properly. How to solve this problem. And keep note I installed following NuGet packages successfully. I'm wroking on windows server 2012 PC. I hosted my app its own IIS

```
NuGet Packages: RC | WebDriver | WebDriverBackedSelenium | Support
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the target page contain any JS code which manipulates the textboxes?

Comment: @AmanB no. This code works fine when I testing through visual studio. problem occur when the publishing

Comment: have you tried putting a longer explicit wait after setting the URL to see if that makes a difference? e.g. `Thread.Sleep(30000);`

Comment: If that makes a difference, than you can implement a wait and poll mechanism which is very common for working with selenium

Comment: @AmanB I already tested with a C# thread as well. But the same thing happens. can you please explain how can I use the poll and wait mechanism

Comment: @Sachith, could you pls confirm if the webpage itself is being loaded when triggered from IIS server? If not check if the server is behind some proxy and then add the proxy details in your script.

Comment: Do you have ChromeDriver in your server? Can you check that it exists in the `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` path?

Comment: @kurakura88 Yes. Chrome driver is in that path.

Comment: @KireetiAnnamaraj You mean this(crims.crib.lk) page? I think this not triggered properly. How can I add proxy details to script? I'm not clear that. As you said I think that web site not triggerd properly

Comment: In Java, we use `System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "<HOST>");` In C-Sharp, depending on your project type, check [here](https://gist.github.com/Kannamaraj/156d0a021a09d607721e73785dd5d23e)

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi , How your issue was resolved? I am facing the same

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi , How your issue was resolved? I am facing the same

Comment: @GHULAMNABI Really sorry to say, I actually do not remember it

Answer (score 1):

This could happen for a multiple of reasons. You need to implement a wait and poll mechanism

This is one way of doing it:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
var element = wait.Until(condition =>
{
    try
    {
        var elementToBeDisplayed = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content-section"));
        return elementToBeDisplayed.Displayed;
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can also use the FluentWait Command and ExpectedConditions example in this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/). This is in java but you can convert that for c#

Comment: Thanks, I tested your code, logs create till time out(mulitple logs), with previous error `Unable to locate element:
{"method":"id","selector":"txtUserName"} `''  Finally this log created `Message :Timed out after 60 seconds`

Comment: Can't identify reason, internet conn is also works fine,

Comment: Try taking a [screenshot on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2) and see if you can figure out anything

Comment: I'm working on windows  server 2012 machine. And i hosted its IIS server.is that can be reason to occour this failier? Have any idea about that?