# Screenshots in Selenium Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Where to store screenshots while running selenium test cases?
I have developed an automation framework using Selenium in C#. I have developed by projrct in Visual Studio and using git Repository. I will be running my test cases through Jenkins.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: What's wrong with the TestResults folder created by Visual Studio? The vstest.console.exe test runner (or `dotnet test`) should allow you to specify the test results directory.

Comment: You can store them almost anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to take screenshots of tests in Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346017/best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-tests-in-selenium-2)

Comment: I am not getting any error guys....I am not sure when my test case will be running in QA environment..where should I be storing my Screenshots.

Comment: I am able to to add the screenshots in visual studio when I run in local...but what about when I run my test cases in Qar through Jenkins job?